# heroku deployment of nodejs app - An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, heroku-postgres

I manually deployed an app on heroic (never done it before and just connected it to my github repository). It says deployed successfully but Im getting the error:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please   
try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

My logs are:

```
2016-10-17T02:39:38.026918+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-10-17T02:39:38.026919+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-10-17T02:39:38.026919+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2016-10-17T02:39:38.026920+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/db/index.js:2:10)
2016-10-17T02:39:38.026921+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-10-17T02:39:38.026921+00:00 app[web.1]:     at loader (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
2016-10-17T02:39:38.026922+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/app/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
2016-10-17T02:39:38.026923+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-10-17T02:39:38.116826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-17T02:39:38.917261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pokemartapp.herokuapp.com request_id=90de2bee-e747-4901-8554-90aa3d57c1f1 fwd="68.105.253.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-17T02:43:14.022540+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pokemartapp.herokuapp.com request_id=589b8bf6-e786-43d6-b6e8-d9b09dca7586 fwd="68.105.253.103" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My server:

```
var chalk = require('chalk');
var db = require('./db');
var server = require('http').createServer();

var createApplication = function () {
    var app = require('./app')(db);
    server.on('request', app); // Attach the Express application.
    require('./io')(server);   // Attach socket.io.
};

var startServer = function () {
    var PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337;

    server.listen(PORT, function () {
        console.log(chalk.blue('Server started on port', chalk.magenta(PORT)));
    });
};

db.sync().then(createApplication).then(startServer).catch(function (err) {
   console.error(chalk.red(err.stack));
});
```

My procfile:

```
web: node server/start.js
```

server/env/index.js:

```
var path = require('path'); var devConfigPath = path.join(__dirname, './development.js'); 
var productionConfigPath = path.join(__dirname, './production.js'); 
var testConfigPath = path.join(__dirname, './testing.js');     
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { module.exports =   
require(productionConfigPath); } 
else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing') { module.exports = require(testConfigPath);    } 
else { module.exports = require(devConfigPath); }
```

What does that mean? I have researched posts with the same problem and the proposed answers but nothing really helps..

Comment: Have you tried adding a Procfile to your project?

Comment: Yes, please see my edit-I have included my procfile code where I start the server. I think the problem could be the database- I exchanged the code where I link to my local database (postgres//localhost/xxx) with the one I have added to my heroku deployed app (with the URL provided on heroku) -not sure if there was anything else I had to do and how that works. Deploying for the first time..

Comment: Hum shouldn't be. You could try setting the node version manually on package.json. I'll add an answer suggesting this

Answer (score 0):

You can try [setting the Node and NPM versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version) to the same you use locally (where it works).

Also make sure that you are not missing a dev dependency, as Heroku won't install them unless you [explicitly configure to do so](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#devdependencies).

UPDATE:

From your comments it seems that when you run your code on production environments like Heroku, the database URL is fetched from an environment variable called `DATABASE_URI`. You can change this variable on `process.env.DATABASE_URI` to match the key of the env var added to your application when you added the addon or you can create an environment variable with the desired values. Please read [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) for more information

Comment: I checked the version of node that I am using and added it to my package.json file but nothing has changed. Im not sure about de dependency-how do I check if Im missing one? Also found this in documentation reg. dependency but don't really understand it: We set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION to true by default to install production dependencies only. If you would like to install devDependencies, you can disable production mode:
$ heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false

Comment: If you have `devDependencies` on package.json they will only be installed on Heroku if you use the command

Comment: Can you add the code that corresponds to this line?  `(/app/server/db/index.js:2:10)` (seems to be the one breaking)

Comment: line 2: var db = require('./_db');

Comment: oh and i don't have any dev dependencies in my package.json file

Comment: It could be your database as you said then. It is probably not being able to find or parse it. Have you added the correct addon to Heroku?

Comment: So I added the heroku postgres database and then just copy pasted the URL (it was a super long mix of random letters-so Im a little unsure if I was suppose to add that URL). I just noticed, I have 2 files: server/env/development.js (here I added the URL of the heroku database) and then I also have server/env/production.js --  "DATABASE_URI": process.env.DATABASE_URI,

Comment: and in my server/env/index.js: var path = require('path');
var devConfigPath = path.join(__dirname, './development.js');
var productionConfigPath = path.join(__dirname, './production.js');
var testConfigPath = path.join(__dirname, './testing.js');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports = require(productionConfigPath);
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing') {
    module.exports = require(testConfigPath); 
} else {
    module.exports = require(devConfigPath);
}

Comment: Pleaaase add code by editing your question because it's very hard to read  it on the comments. I will add my thoughts on my answer, based on your last comment

Comment: sorry I just don't understand it at all..  'change this variable on process.env.DATABASE_URI' -where would I change it -in my env/production.js file? 'to match the key of the env var added to your application' - I can't find any key or env variable on heroku

Comment: Have you added the database addon to Heroku?

Comment: yes it says the heroku database was installed as an add-ons. I was just reading and its like you said- my environment variables are not hardcoded so I need to set them in my heroku configuration - I just don't get how. (It also says I should set my NODE_ENV=production on heroku as well

Comment: Check the link on my answer, you can add config vars and they will be read as env vars by Heroku

Comment: I did read your link, but I don't understand it where I can get the variables from/what to set them to? For example: 'heroku config:get CONFIG-VAR-NAME -s  >> .env' where do I get the config var name from?